# OS partition has 512 bytes clusters, should I convert to 4k?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, defragment, cluster

I made a mistake and formatted the OS partition with 512 bytes cluster size, thinking that this will save a lot of space when storing small files (That was a long time ago, I didn't know that it will increase fragmentation)
So my question is: Should I change it to 4096 bytes to reduce this fragmentation problem (and possibly increase speed) or it's not worth it?

Note: I restored this OS from a backup to a new HDD less than 3 weeks ago and now I'm defragging it (12% fragmented). Seems high for me.

Comment: Fragmentation really depends on your usage. For example if you only write a few MB a day to the drive it will be able to 'place' those bytes much tidier on the drive. If you do a huge amount of data shuffling (like the OS backup you ran) it will be very fragmented just purely from having to place bytes all over the disk. I would say its not worth the hassle as you can only do this at point of Format.

Comment: "like the backup you ran".
You mean that making the backup increases fragmentation? I think it's just 'reading' off the hard disk (and I'm storing the backup file on a different HDD)
or did you mean 'restoring' the backup?

Comment: Yeah sorry if your backing up to another HD then that drive will become fragmented, the restore to your drive will also increase fragmentation. I tend to do a defrag once a week on my drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether you get fragmentation for a drive or not really depends on your usage.  If you are aggressively writing, deleting and re-writing data a lot, then fragmentation can become a problem.

12% fragmentation isn't hugely high, but its above what my drive is - and I've not defragged for a couple of months at least.

The simplest answer is that if you are a heavy user - convert!  Whether you qualify as a heavy user or not is a question only you can answer - but by converting, you can't damage and can potentially get an improvement in service.